# Calling Javascript object methods into on click HTML - JS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two methods in a single object. The first 'Basket.add('clothing-item-name')' which I can put in the onclick. When the user clicks, it adds that item of clothing to the corresponding location in the basket itinery from the paramter 'name'.

How would I use Basket.items() to display added item here with the +1 function created in Basket.add?

I've tried .append(); and .text(); to the div where i wanted the item to increase by 1 each time. I've also written a separate function which just updates the the basket total but doesn't incorporate the method above.

HTML- button

```
<button type="button" value="1" onclick="Basket.add('clothing-item-name')" id="add">ADD TO BASKET</button>
```

HTML - itinery(part of)

```
<li class="tShirt1"><a href="#">T-shirt 1 <span class="amount">  </span></a></li>
```

JS OBJECT

```
var Basket = (function () {

var _items = {};

return {
add: function (name) {
  if (_items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    _items[name] = _items[name] + 1;
  } else {
    _items[name] = 1;
  }
},

items: function () {
  return clone(_items);

  function clone(obj) {
    var target = {};
    for (var i in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        target[i] = obj[i];
      }
    }
    return target;
   }
  }
 };
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand what you're trying to do here. Is it just update span.amount every time you add a new item? If so, you basically can just do something like calling some sort of 'setItems' function whenever you add/remove:

```
    var Basket = (function () {

    var _items = {};

    return {
        add: function (name) {
            if (_items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                _items[name] = _items[name] + 1;
            } else {
                _items[name] = 1;
            }

            this.setItems(name);
        },

        items: function () {
            return clone(_items);

            function clone(obj) {
                var target = {};
                for (var i in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        target[i] = obj[i];
                    }
                }
                return target;
            }
        },
        setItems: function (name) {
            $(".amount").text(_items[name]);
        }
    };
}());
```

[You can check it out on this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/S7GLF/)